# Why git diff doesn't show information on a specific commit and file?

Tags: git, git-diff

I made changes to file `source.json` by removing a line from it. I committed the change (other files were changed as well).  I then made another commit.

Now I want to see the changes I made to `source.json` using `git diff`.

What I do is:

`git diff HEAD^^ -- path/to/source.json`

I don't get any output though (the command's exit status is 0). If I enter `git diff HEAD^^` I do see the change `source.json` along with all other changed files.

This is the output of `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD^`:

```
path/to/AboutUs.js
path/to/Contact.js
path/to/source.json
```

This is the output of `git diff HEAD^^`:

```
diff --git a/path/to/source.json b/path/to/source.json
index 3ba32e950..d86eb9c25 100644
--- a/path/to/source.json
+++ b/path/to/source.json
@@ -565,7 +565,6 @@
-  "someContent": "someContent",
   "someContent2": "someContent2",
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: This is unexpected behaviour as far as I can tell. Your command looks correct to me.

Comment: Try with ~2 instead of ^^

Comment: What directory are you in right now? Note that `git diff` shows full paths, but if you're already in `path/to/`, you'll need to `git diff ... -- source.json` or `git diff ... -- ./source.json` to name the file.

Comment: @torek you were right, the problem was incorrect directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `git diff` *does* allow pathspecs to limit its output to files matching the pathspec, what is sometimes a bit surprising is that these pathspecs are relative to the *current position* within the work-tree.

In other words, if:

> ```
> git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD^
> ```

produces:

> ```
> path/to/AboutUs.js
> path/to/Contact.js
> path/to/source.json
> ```

and you are at the *top level* of your work-tree but then do:

```
cd path/to
```

you will need to use:

```
git diff HEAD^^ -- source.json
```

as the last argument effectively means `./source.json`.

Alternatively, after:

```
git rev-parse --show-cdup
```

prints `../..` you can do:

```
git -C ../.. diff HEAD^^ -- path/to/source.json
```

as the `-C` moves that one `git diff` command temporarily up two levels.  (I've used this general pattern in scripts and aliases, e.g.,

```
git -C "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)" ls-files --other --exclude-standard
```

in a bit of shell code to detect untracked files.)

---

Git is not completely consistent here.  If you wish to view the version of `source.json` that is in commit `HEAD^^` while in this subdirectory, you must run:

```
git show HEAD^^:./source.json
```

as:

```
git show HEAD^^:filename
```

refers to the file named `filename` in the top level of the repository—even though you're still in `path/to`.  The trick for `git show` in particular is that the file name supplied after the commit-specifier is *not* a pathspec argument.  But other Git commands that *do* take pathspecs may in effect assume `:(toplevel)`.

For more about pathspecs, see [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec).